# Windows software to view thumbnail(s) inside JPG files

Tags: windows, gratis, metadata, jpg, thumbnail

Please recommend software to view the thumbnail(s) stored within the metadata inside JPG (JPEG) image files.

I'm not referring to *creating* thumbnails; instead I'm referring to viewing any thumbnails already stored within the metadata.

Must be Windows 7 compatible and gratis.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ExifTool](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to extract the thumbnail (if any) from a Jpeg Image, *(as opposed to generating one from the image data).*

The command:

```
exiftool -b -ThumbnailImage image.jpg > thumbnail.jpg
```

Will extract (as binary **-b** option) the thumbnail (**-ThumbnailImage** command) from `image.jpg` and the output will be piped by **>** to `thumbnail.jpg` all from the command line.

ExifTool is:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Written in Perl *but available as a binary download for Windows or a package for OS-X*
- Cross Platform including Windows *"All Versions" but I haven't tried a recent build on 3.1 or XP*, OS-X, Linux, etc.
- Supports extracting the meta data from lots of file formats
- Support adding, changing or removing metadata from nearly as many file formats.
- Is very fast and powerful.
- Supports renaming the exe file, (or equivalent), to make a shortcut that you can drop files on to do frequent operations.
- If you do anything with photographs you should have a copy.

Comment: Thanks, Steve, for providing the syntax as well.